# PageMenuKit ライブラリを用いた、タブの並びを左揃えにする方法

Tags: swift, cocoapods

スマートニュースを始めとしたニュースアプリで見られるような
横スクロールのタブメニューを実現させたく

以下のサイト様より、PageMenuKitライブラリを利用して実装を試みました。

[ニュース系アプリのユーザインタフェース PageMenuKit の実装 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/magickworx/items/5de63eb926a9447b2665)

しかし、タブの数が画面の横幅よりも狭い場合、タブメニューが中央揃えになる問題があり、
これを左揃えにしたいです。（添付画像をご参照ください）

ソースのどこを触ればよいか分からず困っております、
ご教授いただけませんでしょうか

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

↓このように左揃えにしたいです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 現状のソースコードが質問に含まれていないとアドバイスが付きづらいと思います。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/233556

Answer (score 0):

他のQ&Aサイトの[回答](https://teratail.com/questions/233556#reply-348185)で解決済みのようですので、原文のまま転載いたします。

> このライブラリでは用意されていないのでできません。
>
> もし行いたいのなら、ライブラリ内部のUIPageViewControllerDataSourceを継承している部分を自分で書き換えましょう。
>   ここで、タブが無限に続くように実装されているので、そうならないように実装すれば左寄せにできるかと思います。
>
> または、こういったライトなライブラリで実現できます。
>   https://github.com/EndouMari/TabPageViewController